# How to make a object transparent in windows forms app

Tags: c#, winforms, transparent

I have a simple use case. I have a preview window on which I am displaying a usb webcam. Now this preview window is not clickable i.e. does not detect on click event. As result I want to put a transparent object on top of this preview window. So that I can add on click event to it. 
Is there a way to make any object truly transparent so that it display whatever is going on behind it ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to actually detect clicks on the preview window?

Comment: @Jon we have tried everything. Preview window does not have a click event. Or any event. It is microsoft expression encoder preview window....

Comment: Does "everything" include [subclassing the window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc.aspx) to handle `WM_CLICK`?

Comment: No ... I will try that immediately

Comment: The preview window is a part of a sealed class(LiveDeviceSource) I cannot subclass it.

Comment: @AkashDeshpande what is the base class your `LiveDeviceSource` inherits? Does it have the property `Handle`?

Comment: @KingKing yes it does.

Comment: @AkashDeshpande if so, there is a solution which may help, see my answer.

Comment: @KingKing this seems to be a good solution iwill try it ...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem to this. Solved my problem but might not yours.

I used:
Timer interval was 30ms.
Picture Box
Camera Feed.

I had a timer and on every tick i set it to capture the image from the webcam feed and sent it to a picture box and set the captured image to the picturebox.Image. The picture box filled the view to act as a preview window.

I had click event on the picture box which then let me click on the view and then proceed.

Answer (score 1):

You can hook into your `LiveDeviceSource` to catch the messages sent to it using this technique:

```
public class Form1 : Form { 
   public Form1(){
      InitializeComponent();
      proc = new LiveDeviceSourceProc();
      Load += (s,e) => {            
         proc.AssignHandle(yourLiveDeviceSource.Handle);
      }; 
      proc.Click += (s,e) => {
         //you can also process your code here
      };
   }
   LiveDeviceSourceProc proc;
   public class LiveDeviceSourceProc : NativeWindow {
     protected override void WndProc(ref Message m){
        if(m.Msg == 0x202)//WM_LBUTTONUP   <=> Left Mouse Click
        {
            //process your code here
            if(Click != null) Click(this,EventArgs.Empty);
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
     }
     public event EventHandler Click;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in your form, you have `Enabled` property, and you can do:

```
this.Enabled = false;
```

to make the entire form disabled.

Second, but not recommended, you can create your own transparent control - read about it [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20121226091810/http://www.bobpowell.net/transcontrols.htm).